# How to populate a value when comparing two columns, VLOOKUP or IF?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to create "Sale Rep" summaries by "Shop", where I can simply filter a column by the rep's name, them populate a total sales for each shop next to the relevant filter result.

I'm using this to filter all the Stores by `Scott`:

```
=(filter(D25:D47,A25:A47 = "Scott"))
```

Next, want to associate the Store/Account in `F` to populate with the corresponding value of `E` inside of `G`. So, `G25` should populate the value of `E25` ($724), `G26`  with `E26` ($822), **and `F27` with `E38`** ($511.50)

I don't know how to write the formula correctly, but something like this is what I'm trying to do: `=IF(F25=D25:D38),E25` I know that's not right, and it won't work in a fill down. But I'm basically trying to look for and copy over the correct value match of D and E inside of G. So, `Misty Mountain Medicince` in `F27` will be matched to the value of `E38` and populated in `G27`.

The filter is what's throwing me off, because it's not a simple fill down. And I don't know how to match filtered results from one column to a matched value in another.

Hope the screenshot helps. [Screenshot of table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDZvC.png)

[image: Screenshot of table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Field Rep: Scott` to `Scott` and you might apply:

```
=query(A25:E38,"select D,E where A='"&F24&"'")
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. So terribly sorry for the delay. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey, I just want to say that this solution works really well. I can simply copy a "Scott" sheet then change {F24} to {George} in the new sheet and bam. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Enter the following into G25 and copy down column G   
=(filter(E25:E47, D25:D47 = F25))

or

//  Enter the following into G25 will expand with content in F upto row 47
=ArrayFormula(IF(F25:F47 <> 0, VLOOKUP(F25:F47, D25:E47, 2, FALSE),))
```

Comment: Hey, awesome, and thanks. Sorry for my delayed response. Much appreciated!